# Is the infinite intersection of subgroups still a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $H_i < G$ where $G$ is a group, and $H_i$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then it is true that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} H_i$ still a subgroup?

Comment: Have you tried to prove it is?

Comment: As a general rule, the intersection of a(ny) family of substructures turns out to be a substructure.

Comment: It's easier for finite intersection, not sure if I can apply the same technique for infinite

Comment: @love:  Well, when you're not sure, just try, and see if it works. =]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure it is. It contains $1$, and then if $a, b \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} H_i$, then $a, b \in H_i$ for each $i$, so $a b^{-1} \in H_i$ for each $i$, so $a b^{-1} \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} H_i$.

Comment: "Infinite intersection" need not be countable...

Comment: @GEdgar, I answered the question as formulated in the question body, of course the very same argument works for an arbitrary intersection.